# Powershell: Prefix string to data inside a .txt file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hi I'm completely new to Powershell so pardon me if this question has a really simple answer.

I would like to use Powershell to look thru a textfile, get all values and prefix and post fix these values with a character.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a prefix and suffix to each line of a file (with default command aliases this would be a lot shorter, but full names are clearer):

```
get-content input-file | `
    foreach-object -process { "Prefix" + $_ + "Suffix" } | `
    out-file output-file
```

Add `-encoding UTF8` to the `out-file` to override the default encoding (UTF-16).

To do this in place `output-file` will need to be a temporary file and then replace the `input-file` after the processing has completed or read the input file into memory.